# unable to turn on switch while reloading tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

i had switch in my tableview when switch is on i need to change views inside tableview cell for that i have written

```
 -(void)didchangeswitchpostion:(UISwitch *)sender{

    [tasklogtableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[reloadindexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

In cell for row at index path i had done

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{

    static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cellidentifier";

    cell=(TaskLogTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {

        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TaskLogTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];  
    }

    if ([cell.autoswitch isOn]) {
        cell.lblfrom.hidden=YES;
        cell.lblhours.hidden=YES;
        cell.lblfromtime.hidden=YES;
      }

    return cell;
}
```

but i was unable to turn othe switch on, is there any problem with reloading cell.

Comment: Make sure, the switch control superview is not a view like UILabel, because can't got click events,  and make sure do not any clear background color views cover it, you can see the switch, but can't get click events.

Comment: you need a else statement for `if ([cell.autoswitch isOn])`  and another is how did you assign BOOL to `cell.autoswitch`? you need to have a 'selected indexVariable' for checking if that's the index where you turned the switch on..

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `cell.autoswitch` to decide what to do. When the switch is changed you should be updating your data model and then reloading the row (or just updating the cell directly), and this update should use the data model to decide what to do.

Using the cell doesn't work because of cell reuse and new cell instances being created. Trying to use the cell is also a bad design...

Comment: but based on switch state i need to update my date model for that i was using if(cell.autoswitch.on),but its not working

Comment: you need to pass the state of the switch back when it changes, then trigger the reload. You already have `didchangeswitchpostion:` and somehow you seem to know `reloadindexpath` so you know the switch too?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps:

1. On the switch action, find what is the index path of the switch that is tapped. Store that index path in an instance var so that you can compare this index path later while configuring and returning cell from the 'cellForRowAtindexpath'. Also save the switch status whether on or off.
2. reload the table which will call cellForRowAtIndexPath again for the table cells
3. Compare the stored index path (done the 1st step) with the current index path path in the cellForRowAtIndexpath: method, if it's the same row & section, then set the state of the switch in that cell to the saved value (done in the 1st step)